# Multiple functions but one is failing

Tags: python, function

I'm coding a process to pull information from a text file, turn the file from strings into integers, squaring the integers, and summing the squares before finally printing the result. The final portion of the code (summing the squares) is not working and I cannot identify why. I'm using Python 3.7.2. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"""
Use the functions from the previous three problems to implement a main() program that computes the sums of the squares of the numbers read from a file.
Your program should prompt for a file name and print out the sum of the squares of the numbers in the file.
Hint: You may want to use readline()

Test Cases
Input(s)  :  Output(s)
4numsin.txt  

"""
def main():
    f = open("4numsin.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        strNumber = line
        number = []
        result = []

        def toNumbers():
            for n in strNumber:
                n = int(strNumber)
                x = number.append(n)
            return number
        toNumbers()

        for line in number:
            def squareEach():
                z = 0
                result = []
                while number != []:
                    z = number.pop(0)
                    a = int(z) ** 2
                    b = result.append(a)
                print(strNumber, result)
            squareEach()

        while result != []:
            def Total():
                i = 0
                theSum = 0
                i = result.pop()
                theSum += i
            print(theSum)
            Total()
main()

"""Text File:
4numsin.txt
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
"""
```

Comment: "is not working" is a much too imprecise error description. What is the error or output, what is the expected output and behavior (edit the question to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: Sounds like you know one is not working. Which one and how did you determine this?

Comment: I think you'll probably find that if you don't define a function inside a loop your code might work. You really shouldn't ever define a function inside a loop. It has many pitfalls, and the only advantage I can think of (off the top of my head) is if you are doing things with mutable parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of issues in it. Never define a function inside a loop. This is not a good programming practice and affects your program a lot. For example, When you use result=[] within the loop, everytime the value of result is made empty and the statement result.append(a) only has the latest value in it. Also you have declared result=[] twice. Same with other variables. Always try passing and returning variables when you use many functions. Change your program like this.

```
def readfile(filepath):
    #Your code to read the contents and store them
    return number_list

def squares(n):
    #code to square the numbers, store and return the numbers
    return ans

def Total():
    #code to calculate the sum
    # you can also check out the built-in sum() function
    return sum

def main():
    numbers = readfile(filepath)
    sq = squares(numbers)
    result = Total(sq)
```

Comment: I would say, only define a function in a loop *if that's what you mean to do*. There are certainly valid use-cases...

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I do not like utilizing the function within a loop because I don't think it is as easy to follow. I really like the way you have everything defined and how easy the code is to follow. This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong in your code. My basic rule is to make each step its own function. You can do this whole thing in one function but it makes it hard to add things later on.

```
# Opens the file and appends each number to a list, returns list
def open_file(filename):
    output = []
    f = open(filename, "r")
    for line in f:
        output.append(int(line.strip()))
    return output

# Takes an input like a list and squared each number, returns the list
def square_number(input):
    return [num*num for num in input]

# sums the list
def sum_numbers(input):
    return sum(input)

# the start, function calls within function calls
the_sum = sum_numbers(square_number(open_file('4numsin.txt')))

#check the result
print(the_sum)
>> 204
```

See how more efficient it is to have separate methods/functions?

```
# look at other things
print(open_file('4numsin.txt'))
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

print(sum_numbers(open_file('4numsin.txt')))
>> 36
```

Comment: I really like the way you have everything defined and the code is much easier to follow. Honestly, I've learned a lot just from looking through this suggestion.